# Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined at ./node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.js:831:26

Tags: node.js, postgresql, serverless, typeorm, amazon-aurora

I am getting this error when I execute the below code , when the line queryRunner.connect() runs I am getting this error but using the same connection I can able to run the application using repository , same is working fine in with local postgres and node app , I am getting this issue only when I connect aurora server less form lambda function, any one here please let know what could be the reason I checked  connectionManager.has("default"); which is returning true

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

// get a connection and create a new query runner
const connection = getConnection();
const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();

// establish real database connection using our new query runner
await queryRunner.connect();
```

In driver file I found out that in the below line _this.master is undefined which is causing this not sure why I am getting this error  even though connection is active

```
 _this.master.connect(function (err, connection, release)
```